# method returns a string......but why?

Tags: python, object

I am just coming to grips with Python so am trying to grasp 'rules of thumb' so I can understand how the bits and pieces work together.

So for this code:

```
string = "Hello World"
string.replace ("World", "Mars")
print string (which would equal "Hello World")
```

I understand that it doesn't change the data object and in order to do that you would need to assign a variable.

```
hello = string.replace("World", "Mars")
print hello
```

I'm more wondering if returning a string is just something typical of methods. Or is there some greater underlying rule here. Because when I think about a function you can't change a data object there either unless you assign it a variable. So is this a general rule of thumb in Python? That you cannot alter an object without doing:

```
object = altering code
```

I hope all this makes sense?

Comment: @user2246674 Why don't you post that as an answer? It's short, simple, and to the point.

Comment: Also, this is not specific to Python.

Comment: Yeah I totally would ticked that

Comment: @Ryaminal I wouldn't know that sorry.

Comment: @Danrex Oh, don't be sorry. I wasn't trying to be a jerk, just an observation in case you want to move to another language.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Strings in Python are immutable - they *can't* be changed. In this sense, Python strings are much like numbers. The *result* of string-manipulation operators/methods has to be used.

Now, *mutable* objects are designed to be changed: lists and dictionaries are mutable objects - most (all standard?) side-effecting methods return `None` (showing that it is the *mutation* that is of importance).

Comment: Cool well explained. Eight minutes and I'll tick you.